# how to use GROUP BY based on 2 specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which looks like this :

[image]

each **ticket id** can have multiple **order issue**. On each row I need to calculate **ticket full revenue** as below : SUM(**revenue**) of all **item**s within the same **ticket id**

So in my case, **ticket id** has 3 **item**s (10,20,30) so the **ticket full revenue** = 30+5+15 = 50 we add it in each row for that specific **ticket id**. it doesn't matter if the **ticket id** has multiple **order issue**, it's counted only once.

I am struggling to make it work. Here is my query

```
Select [ticket id], [order issue], item, qty, [unit price], 
qty*[unit price] AS revenue, 
SUM(qty*[unit price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ticket id]) AS [ticket full revenue]
From orders
Group by [ticket id], [order issue], item, qty, [unit price]
Order by [ticket id]
```

The query returns 100 as it's counting the revenue for the **order issue** 'email not provided' and 'adress not provide'. but my logic it should count only once the same **ticket id**
I tried to adjust by dividing the value by count distinct value of concat [ticket id] and [order issue] but still not working.

`(SUM(qty*[unit price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ticket id])) / (Count(distinct concat([ticket id], [order issue]))) AS [ticket full revenue]`

any suggestion please what I am doing wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Well, let's look a little closer at your image - and that is before berating you for posting critical information as an image. It appears that the query that produces the output is incorrect since it is duplicating rows. Is that the case? That would explain why your summed number is doubled - would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [ticket id], [order issue], item, qty, [unit price], 
(SELECT SUM(item) FROM orders as B WHERE b.ticket_id = a.ticket_id GROUP BY b.ticket_id) as 'ticket full revenue'
FROM orders A
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table has *redundancy* and that can hurt your database in multiple ways.

Anyway, in order to compute the value you want, you'll need a query that clears out the redundancy and then a simple `SUM()` will do.

For example:

```
select
  o.*,
  y.revenue
from orders o
join (
  select
    ticket_id,
    sum(revenue)
  from (
    select
      ticket_id,
      item,
      max(revenue) as revenue
    from orders
    group by ticket_id, item
  ) x
  group by ticket_id
) y on y.ticket_id = o.ticket_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use window functions:

```
select o.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then revenue end) over (partition by ticket_id) as full_revenue
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ticket_id, item order by item) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o;
```

If each order issue has all the items, you can dispense with the subquery:

```
select o.*,
       sum(revenue) over (partition by ticket_id, order_issue) as full_revenue
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ticket_id, item order by item) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o;
```